# Is there a way to write multiple line Pre's in javascript

Tags: javascript, pre

So I am trying to write a code where it has a pre tag and it turns into another value with multiple lines. Here is my code:

```
var pre = document.getElementById("text");
pre.innerHTML = "
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
"
```

When I do this it gives me error: 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`
The line which gives me the error is

```
pre.innerHTML = "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for Mulitline strings**

```js
var pre = document.getElementById("text");
pre.innerText = `
  Line 1
  Line 2
  Line 3
  Line 4
`
```

Comment: Yes this works thank you!